# setup nginx to serve django and wordpress blog as subdirectory

Tags: php, nginx, wordpress, django

```
upstream django {
    server unix:///home/ubuntu/web/www.mysite.com/uwsgi-tutorial/mysite/mysite.sock; # for a file socket
}
server {
    listen      80;
    server_name mysite.com www.mysite.com; 
    charset     utf-8;
    client_max_body_size 75M;   # adjust to taste

    #--------PHP PART -----------------------
    location /blog {
                alias /var/www;
                try_files $uri =404;
                index index.php index.html;
        }

        location ~ /blog/.+\.php$ {
                include /etc/nginx/fastcgi_params;
                fastcgi_pass 127.0.0.1:9000;
                fastcgi_index index.php;
                fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME /var/www/$fastcgi_script_name;
        }

        location ~ /\.ht {
                deny all;
        }
    #------------------------------- 
    location /media  {
        alias /home/ubuntu/web/www.mysite.com/uwsgi-tutorial/mysite/media;
    }

    location /static {
        alias /home/ubuntu/web/www.mysite.com/uwsgi-tutorial/mysite/static;
    }

    location / {
        uwsgi_pass  django;
        include     /home/ubuntu/web/www.mysite.com/uwsgi-tutorial/mysite/uwsgi_params;
    }
}
```

I have nginx<-->uwsgi<-->django working just fine.
mysite.com                     [django : working] 
mysite.com/blog/index.php      [wordpress not working]

INFO : https://www.digitalocean.com/community/articles/how-to-install-wordpress-with-nginx-on-ubuntu-12-04 [followed this blog to setup wordpress part]

Comment: What is the problem you are having?

Comment: i have no idea how to redirect mysite.com/blog to wordpress part using nginx settings. rightnow i am getting nginx 404 file not found

Comment: Does it works if you type exactly mysite.com/blog/index.php ?

Comment: mysite.com shows django site. but mysite/blog/index.php gives : File not Found.[not 404 nginx]